# Log4net is not logging anything

Tags: asp.net, logging, log4net

I cannot get log4net working on my ASP.NET project. My web.config looks like this:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
 </configSections>
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="CardGame.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

And my LogHelper class looks this:

```
public class LogHelper
{
    private static LogHelper _instance = new LogHelper();
    private static volatile object _lock = new object();
    public ILog Logger;

    public static LogHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new LogHelper();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private LogHelper()
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogHelper));
        Logger.Debug("Debug message");
        Logger.Warn("Warn message");
        Logger.Error("Error message");
        Logger.Fatal("Fatal message");
    }
}
```

I have also added the line

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

to Application_Start in global.asax.cs

However none of the loggings in the constructor works and I am running out of ideas on why it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the user running the app has write permissions on the target folder.

I always test that case by adding `everyone` and restarting the pool. If it works you know it's a permissions issue, otherwise check the code/config.

Comment: This seemed to be the case. I was runnig the application pool with the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Switching that to my windows user fixed the problem.

Comment: You Should do the other way around, add that user to the folder.  I think these user has prefix of `NT\`

Answer (score 2):

Which version are you using ? this is setting from my web.config

```
    <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="Log.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
        <maximumFileSize value="15MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!--<conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms [%thread] %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />-->
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <!-- Options are "ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL" and "OFF". -->
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```